# Python zipfile extract files from directory inside a zip file

Tags: python, zip, python-zipfile

I need to extract some files inside a directory in a zip file.

The main problem is that I want to extract only the contents from this directory, not the directory itself with all the files inside.

I've tried by iterating on them using `namelist()` or tweaking it with `zipfile.Path()`, unsuccessfully.

This works but it extracts the directory with the files (like `extractall()` does). Path doesn't work because raises `KeyError` saying that the item doesn't exist yet it does.

```py
for zip_file in zip_files:
    with zipfile.ZipFile(os.path.join(home_path, zip_file), 'r') as zip_ref:
        files = [n for n in zip_ref.namelist()]
        zip_ref.extractall(os.path.join(home_path, 'dir'), members=files)
```

Comment: _I want to extract only the contents from this directory, not the directory itself with all the files inside._ What do you mean by that?

Comment: @AMC, I have file.zip that contains a dir called foo with x files inside. I need those x files to be extracted from it, without the dir called foo. My solution extracts foo/x1, foo/x2 etc. and I want my x1 and x2 inside a dir that I want to choose. I made a script that works that extracts the dir and then moves the files where I want but I want to do this one shot without extracting everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

written from my mobile but I expect it to work:

```
from pathlib import Path

with ZipFile(zipfile_path, "r") as zf:
            for f in zf.namelist():
                if f.startswith('/'):
                    continue
                
                source = zf.open(f)
                target = open(target_dir / Path(f).name, "wb")

                with source, target:
                    shutil.copyfileobj(source, target)
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I was trying to do by using Path. Thanks!